# Cannot infer T , generics multiple types

Tags: go

```
func CreateSlice[T int | string](length int) []T {
    return make([]T, length)
}
```

Try to learn `go` and want to play with `slices` and `generics` . Above you can see that I want to say `T`  can be or `int` or `string` => `T int | string` . Compiler say nothing about this case when I create this function , but on the moment I call it , it says `cannot infer T`

`slices.CreateSlice(10)`

Is there any restriction , or do I make some mistaces in syntax ?

Answer (score 4):

The compiler cannot determine `T` from `slices.CreateSlice(10)` because `T` is not used as an argument.  Fix by specifying `T` explicitly:

```
 slices.CreateSlice[int](10)    // evaluates to []int with len(10)
 slices.CreateSlice[string](10) // evaluates to []string with len(10)
```